# Major speed issues across the network?

Tags: support, performance

Starting about 40 minutes ago (~13:45 GMT 3 November), SO, SE, and MSE at least all seem to be **really** slow. I'm not seeing issues with non-SE sites (not that that's scientific). Is there some network issue or similar?

Comment: *shakes magic 8-ball*: Yup, it's down. Also see http://isitdownrightnow.com/stackoverflow.com.html

Comment: Our SRE guys are looking into it right now...

Comment: @MartijnPieters: :-) Whereas when I did that with downforeveryoneorjustme.com it happened to say it was just me, so...intermittent.

Comment: Perhaps the [new network hardware](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/101272770169/data-center-maintenance-sat-nov-1-2014) tripped and fell when the weekday traffic load started to come in.

Comment: Personally, I think someone plugged a switch into itself.

Comment: Yeah, it's been coming and going. Working well at this particular moment (for me).

Comment: I blame indian hackers

Comment: @JanDvorak blame babas also :)

Comment: @Dean looks like it's all good now, any updates on what happened?

Comment: @ShadowWizard some botnet leveraging older browsers (IE8) to DDOS the home page :(

Comment: That's bad news :(

Comment: @Dean oh, that makes some sense - Stack Overflow got its share of enemies... hopefully it won't happen too often! :/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We are aware of the speed issues and are currently investigating.

Hopefully this is something that will be easy/fast to fix/mitigate.

Stay tuned.

---

We were hit by a botnet causing the slowdowns seen earlier.

Once a full post-mortem of the event has been finished, it will be posted on https://www.stackstatus.net

Comment: but what went wrong ?

Comment: @TGMCians who knows? Also, who cares?

Comment: @TGMCians - we are still looking into the causes.

Comment: @Jan well, last time there was a major downtime we got stickers and T-shirts so many should care! :D

Comment: @Jan */me curious..*

Comment: @TGMCians - _you_ are? So are our SRE team ;)

Comment: *facepalm* ...:D

Comment: /me blames CloudFlare, even though that probably isn't the problem >:D

Comment: */me blames a solar flare*

Comment: Seems to be improving.

Comment: @Oded So you got hit by a botnet and you didn't even go down? Just got slow? That seems impressive!

Comment: @ɥʇǝS - well... yeah... that's true. We aren't behind cloudflare yet - dunno how it would look like if we were.